# How to change Google Mail's smart labels?

Tags: gmail, label, redmine, typo3

I am using Google Mail for my mails.

Google got this Smart Label feature. Which marks mails automatically as bill or advertisement. This is my problem.

I don't know why, but when I receive mails from **forge.typo3.org** they become marked as advertisement. Mails from other redmine instances are marked as notification.

The question is: How can I tell Google Mail to use "notification" label instead of "advertisement" for mails from **forge.typo3.org**?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found an option for that.
Just open the menu and click "Report wrong category" (screenshot is in german)

[image: Reply menu in gmail]

And then you can switch to the right category:

[image: Choose right category]

If this really helps, time will show.

**Update:** The steps above just report the wrong category. You are also able to set your own filter in the gmail settings. There you can set a label to a mail and/or a category. I just did not find this category rule option. That's the solution for my question.

Answer (score 1):

I moved (with drag&drop) the e-mails from Forge manually from the "wrong" tab to the tab I wanted the message to show up. GMail then asks if you always want to perform this action on all e-mails from this sender, which you can answer with "yes". That fixed the problem for me.

Edit:

This is some kind of strange. This (see screenshot below) appears when I move messages around in tabs.

[image: GMail drag&drop TYPO3 forge]

Comment: When I move mails to correct category (by drag&drop) in Inbox, I don't get such message.